# IMO 1990 Graph Theory Problem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

So I saw this solution for IMO 1990 P2:

Problem 2: Suppose n≥3, and let S be a set of 2n−1 distinct points on a circle. Assume that exactly k points of S are colored black. A coloring of S is called "good" if there is at least one pair of the black points such that the interior of one of the arcs between the pair contains exactly n points of S. Find the least value of k so that each coloring of S be "good".

Solution: Consider a graph G whose vertices represent the points and there is an
edge between two vertices if the interior of one of the arcs they define has exactly n
vertices. We want to show that when we color k vertices, two adjacent vertices have
been colored. Since the degree of each vertex is 2, Exercise 4.1.4 shows that G is
the union of disjoint cycles. Note that if we number the vertices from 1 to 2n − 1,
then 1 is adjacent to n + 2 and n + 2 is adjacent to 2n + 3, which is vertex 4. Thus 1
and 4 are in the same cycle. If 2n − 1 is not divisible by 3, then G consists of only
one cycle, so k = n is clearly the desired number. If 2n−1 is divisible by 3, then the
graph is formed by three disjoint cycles of length 2n−1
3 . Thus we can color at most 2n−1
3 −1
2 = n−2
3 vertices of one cycle without getting consecutive vertices colored.
Thus k = 3 · ((n − 2)/3) + 1 = n − 1 is the number we want in this case.

I don't undestand why it says that each vertice will have DEGREE 2, could someone explain this to me?

Comment: You can use this little guide for better formatting. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: A point is adjacent to the point $n+1$ points away clockwise and also to the one $n+1$ points away counterclockwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The degree is the number of other vertices each vertex has edges connecting to. In this case, the two connected vertices are found by counting n+1 points in each direction along the circle.